# Iterating over an array doesn't do things in order?

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

The code below, when run works but it seems like it somehow doesn't append the posts in order (sometimes `post_2` is first and `post_4` second):

```
var posts = [
    "post_1.md",
    "post_2.md",
    "post_3.md",
    "post_4.md",
    "post_5.md",
    "post_6.md",
    "post_7.md"];

for (var i in posts) {
    $.ajax({
        url: "posts/" + posts[i],
        context: document.body,
        success: function (mdText) {
            var converter = new Showdown.converter();
            var htmlText = converter.makeHtml(mdText);
            $("body").append(htmlText);
        }
    });
}
```

It loops over the elements in the array, and for each element it downloads a Markdown document, converts it to HTML, and appends it to the body. I tried a simple `for` loop as well as Underscore's `_.each()` function. All three have the same results, when run they don't append the documents in order (so when I click refresh, the titles are in different orders). Any ideas why this happens and a way to fix it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`$.ajax` is an asynchronous function, meaning all of your `$.async` functions are happening in parallel and will append to the body in the order that they complete (Which can obviously vary depending on the size of the document they are fetching and general networking latencies).

You may wish to look into the [async.js](https://github.com/caolan/async) library, which would allow you to run your AJAX calls in parallel and then execute a callback when all have completed. You'd want to use the `async.parallel` function, which will pass the final callback the result of each AJAX call as an array.

Comment: Thank you. Exactly what I was looking for; not sure how I didn't notice this myself.

Comment: @RafalChmiel Glad it was what you were looking for, if you don't mind please mark this as the accepted answer :)

Comment: Sure, additionally, I've simply set `async: false` when I looked at the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) to make this synchronous.

Comment: @RafalChmiel Don't make them synchronous; that requires an even longer wait as only one request goes out at a time. Instead, you should be handling the deferred returned from `$.ajax` and responding to its resolved promises.

Answer (score 2):

This is precisely the type of thing jQuery's [`$.when`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.when/) and [`deferred.done`](http://api.jquery.com/deferred.done/) are meant to help with. You pass a series of deferreds (jQuery's `$.ajax` returns a deferred), and when their promises resolve you can handle each of them individually. Here's a modified example from jQuery's API docs themselves:

```js
$.when( $.ajax("/page1.php"), $.ajax("/page2.php") ).done(function( a1, a2 ) {
  /* a1 and a2 are arguments resolved for the page1 and page2 ajax requests */
});
```

The callback function passed into `.done` will only be ran when the promises have all resolved. So even though the request for page2 might complete before page1, we aren't concerned. Our code isn't called until all of the requests have been completed.

In your particular case, where the number of asynchrnous requests is not known, and varies, you might find more success using `func.apply` instead:

```js
var reqs = [];

reqs.push( $.ajax("post_1.md"), $.ajax("post_2.md"), $.ajax("post_3.md") );

$.when.apply(this, reqs).done(function () {
    $.each(arguments, function (index, value) {
        console.log( value[0] );
    });
});
```

Comment: @RafalChmiel I've updated the code above to more closely resemble your situation.